# Make an android countdown

Tags: java, android, date, counter, countdown

Here I want an android downcount app for next football match that takes date from internet and shows the remaining time to start the match. After doing some research i got the following code but it counts only date i.e. yyyy-MM-dd but i want to make it count date and time (yyyy-MM-dd-hr:min).

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvDay, tvHour, tvMinute, tvSecond, tvEvent;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout1, linearLayout2;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUI();
        countDownStart();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void initUI() {
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll2);
        tvDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerDay);
        tvHour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerHour);
        tvMinute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerMinute);
        tvSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerSecond);
        tvEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvevent);
    }

    // //////////////COUNT DOWN START/////////////////////////
    public void countDownStart() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd");
                    // Here Set your Event Date
                    Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2016-12-30");
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                        long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                                - currentDate.getTime();
                        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                        diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                        long seconds = diff / 1000;
                        tvDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                        tvHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                        tvMinute.setText("" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                        tvSecond.setText("" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    } else {
                        linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tvEvent.setText("Android Event Start");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        // handler.removeMessages(0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    // //////////////COUNT DOWN END/////////////////////////
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvevent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Android Event Start"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerDay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerDay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Days"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerHour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerHour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Hour"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerMinute"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerMinute"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Minute"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerSecond"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerSecond"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Second"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what exacty are you asking

Comment: "it counts only date i.e. yyyy-MM-dd" but you wrote `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd");`, so I don't understand what else you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd");
                // Here Set your Event Date
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2016-12-30");
```

You need to add Hours and Minutes to the formatting, like the code below ->

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Do the same with the futureDate as well